# Unreal Fails to Build on Linux

Tags: compiling

I'm trying to install UE4 on my Ubuntu 20.04. I keep getting this issue:

```
~/UnrealEngine$ make
bash "/home/zhihan/UnrealEngine/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Linux/Build.sh" CrashReportClient Linux Shipping
Building CrashReportClient...
Using 'git status' to determine working set for adaptive non-unity build.
Creating makefile for CrashReportClient (no existing makefile)
Performing full C++ include scan (no include cache file)
Using clang version '3.9.1' (string), 3 (major), 9 (minor), 1 (patch)
Building UnrealHeaderTool...
Using 'git status' to determine working set for adaptive non-unity build.
Creating makefile for UnrealHeaderTool (no existing makefile)
Using clang version '3.9.1' (string), 3 (major), 9 (minor), 1 (patch)
Using bundled libc++ standard C++ library.
Using fast way to relink circularly dependent libraries (no FixDeps).
Performing 27 actions (8 in parallel)
[3/27] Compile SharedPCH.Core.h
[4/27] Compile Module.UnrealHeaderTool.cpp
[2/27] Compile PCH.CoreUObject.h
[1/27] Compile PCH.Core.h
In file included from /home/zhihan/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealHeaderTool/Development/Core/SharedPCH.Core.h:40:
In file included from /home/zhihan/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/CoreSharedPCH.h:7:
In file included from Runtime/Core/Public/Misc/Exec.h:6:
In file included from Runtime/Core/Public/Misc/AssertionMacros.h:6:
In file included from Runtime/Core/Public/HAL/PlatformMisc.h:22:
In file included from Runtime/Core/Public/Linux/LinuxPlatformMisc.h:12:
In file included from Runtime/Core/Public/Linux/LinuxSystemIncludes.h:34:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/sysctl.h:21:2: error: "The <sys/sysctl.h>
header is deprecated and will be removed." [-Werror,-W#warnings]
#warning "The <sys/sysctl.h> header is deprecated and will be removed."
^
In file included from enter code here/home/zhihan/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealHeaderTool/Development/CoreUObject/PCH.CoreUObject.h:46:
In file included from /home/zhihan/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/CoreUObject/Private/CoreUObjectPrivatePCH.h:6:
In file included from Runtime/Core/Public/CoreMinimal.h:27:
In file included from Runtime/Core/Public/HAL/PlatformMisc.h:22:
In file included from Runtime/Core/Public/Linux/LinuxPlatformMisc.h:12:
In file included from Runtime/Core/Public/Linux/LinuxSystemIncludes.h:34:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/sysctl.h:21:2: error: "The <sys/sysctl.h>
header is deprecated and will be removed." [-Werror,-W#warnings]
#warning "The <sys/sysctl.h> header is deprecated and will be removed."
^
In file included from /home/zhihan/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealHeaderTool/Development/Core/PCH.Core.h:46:
In file included from /home/zhihan/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Private/CorePrivatePCH.h:12:
In file included from Runtime/Core/Public/Misc/AssertionMacros.h:6:
In file included from Runtime/Core/Public/HAL/PlatformMisc.h:22:
In file included from Runtime/Core/Public/Linux/LinuxPlatformMisc.h:12:
In file included from Runtime/Core/Public/Linux/LinuxSystemIncludes.h:34:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/sysctl.h:21:2: error: "The <sys/sysctl.h>
header is deprecated and will be removed." [-Werror,-W#warnings]
#warning "The <sys/sysctl.h> header is deprecated and will be removed."
^
In file included from /home/zhihan/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealHeaderTool/Development/UnrealHeaderTool/Module.UnrealHeaderTool.cpp:2:
In file included from /home/zhihan/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealHeaderTool/Private/BaseParser.cpp:3:
In file included from Programs/UnrealHeaderTool/Private/BaseParser.h:5:
In file included from Runtime/Core/Public/CoreMinimal.h:27:
In file included from Runtime/Core/Public/HAL/PlatformMisc.h:22:
In file included from Runtime/Core/Public/Linux/LinuxPlatformMisc.h:12:
In file included from Runtime/Core/Public/Linux/LinuxSystemIncludes.h:34:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/sysctl.h:21:2: error: "The <sys/sysctl.h>
header is deprecated and will be removed." [-Werror,-W#warnings]
#warning "The <sys/sysctl.h> header is deprecated and will be removed."
^
1 error generated.
1 error generated.
1 error generated.
1 error generated.
ERROR: UBT ERROR: Failed to produce item: /home/zhihan/UnrealEngine/Engine/Binaries/Linux/libUnrealHeaderTool-Core.so
Total build time: 2.88 seconds (Local executor: 0.00 seconds)
Error: UnrealHeaderTool failed for target 'CrashReportClient' (platform: Linux, module info: /home/zhihan/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/CrashReportClient/Shipping/CrashReportClient.uhtmanifest, exit code: OtherCompilationError (5)).
make: *** [Makefile:277：CrashReportClient-Linux-Shipping] Error 5
```

How to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

- edit UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Linux/LinuxSystemIncludes.h
- `//#include <sys/sysctl.h>` (remove redundant include file)